# Docker+Django, server running but welcome page not showing

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

When I run my `dockerfile`, I get the right output:

```
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 31, 2017 - 11:00:32
Django version 1.11.3, using settings 'tufleur.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8002/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM django:onbuild
# Install Python dependencies
RUN  pip install django
#CMD ["pwd"]
RUN ./manage.py makemigrations
RUN ./manage.py migrate
#RUN ./manage.py collectstatic
EXPOSE 8002
#Run Server
CMD ./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002
```

But in the browser the django welcome page is not showing,

can you help me to find the problem, because I can't find any

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you need to change

```
CMD ./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002
```

to

```
CMD ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
```

This is because you want to listen on all interfaces inside the container. Listening to `127.0.0.1` inside the container will allow you to access the app only from inside the container.

Next when you run this file, you need to make sure to map the port to the host os

```
docker run -it -p 8002:8002 <imageid>
```

Now your app would be accessible on `localhost:8082` on the docker host. If your docker host is inside a VM and then you need to use `<VMIP>:8082` to access the app